# Ebay Feed API ( migration from file exchange)

Tags: api, ebay-api

I am new to development on the ebay api. I am aware that the File exchange offered to list items on ebay is being deprecated soon. Now Ebay have suggested migrating to their feed api. After having read the documentation about 3 times. I am still getting all kinds of errors:

First off the migration process begins with obtaining the access token. [image]

These are some of the errors I encountered.
This has stopped the development process as when I make calls to the createTask method on the api using my application access token not user access token I get the following error:

> {
> "errors": [
> {
> "errorId": 160002,
> "domain": "API_FEED",
> "subdomain": "Selling",
> "category": "REQUEST",
> "message": "The authentication scope https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.guest.order https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.item.feed https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.marketing https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.product.feed https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.marketplace.insights https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.proxy.guest.order https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.item.bulk is incorrect for 'feed_type' FX_LISTING. Refer to documentation for details about the scopes.",
> "parameters": [
> {
> "name": "scope",
> "value": "https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.guest.order https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.item.feed https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.marketing https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.product.feed https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.marketplace.insights https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.proxy.guest.order https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.item.bulk"
> },
> {
> "name": "feedType",
> "value": "FX_LISTING"
> }
> ]
> }
> ]
> }

Basically none of the steps that ebay have put on their documentation work. I need help please. I have seen that other people have these issues but are almost always left unanswered or answered unclearly. If someone could please guide me on how to actually upload a FILE EXCHANGE listing on this feed api or just enumerate clear steps that actually work, I would be most grateful!

Answer (score 0):

For feed api, ebay says this..

> Note: This is a (Limited Release) API available only to select developers approved by business units.

Are you sure u have access to the same?

Do u want to upload product data or download?